# What is the best sort key and partition key for a self join on id and date in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm joining a table on itself using an id and a date in order to do something like : 

    `SELET t1.id, t1.date, SUM(whatwever)
    FROM analytics.my_summary_by_day t1
    LEFT JOIN analytics.my_summary_by_day t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
     AND DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.date,t2.date)>=-30
     AND DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.date,t2.date)<0`

Should I create my_summary_table like that for better performance on the particular query above :

```
CREATE my_summary_table (
  id int,
  date datetime
) DISTKEY(id) SORTKEY(date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "Choose the Best Sort Key" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html

> - If you frequently join a table, specify the join column as both the sort key and the distribution key.
>
>   - Doing this enables the query optimizer to choose a sort merge join instead of a slower hash join. Because the data is already sorted on the join key, the query optimizer can bypass the sort phase of the sort merge join.

Try the following and review your `EXPLAIN` plan to see if you get a merge join.

```
CREATE my_summary_table (
  id int,
  date datetime
) DISTKEY(id) SORTKEY(id, date);
```

Comment: Yes I tried that one it divided by 5 the query time !